# rsa data decryption error.the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, rsa

I  am doing encryption descryption with rsa provider and it is giving following errors.

rsa data decryption error.the system cannot find the file specified.

Any one have any idea I am also using identity in web.cofig. I have also given all rights to rsa folder where the key generating but still it is there.

Another strange thing is that when i create rdp session with user i given in the identity section then its working fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this runs under that user account - maybe you need to give permissions to ASPNET, IUSR, IWAM or NETWORKSERVICE rather than the user account the application runs under.